# Lodash merge array with dictionary object key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, merge, lodash

I have an array

```
var keys = ['Name','Id'];
```

which I want to merge with the dictionary object below

```
var projects = {
 "project1": "11111",
 "project2": "22222",
 "project3": "33333",
 };
```

to produce the output below

```
output =
[
{ Name:"project1", Id:"11111"},
{ Name:"project2", Id:"22222"},
{ Name:"project3", Id:"33333"},
]
```

I have tried using

```
console.log(_.zipObject(keys, projects));
```

but this fails woefully

How do I do this using lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have asked to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) specifically, you can use [**`_.map`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map).

**DEMO**

```js
var projects = {
 "project1": "11111",
 "project2": "22222",
 "project3": "33333",
 };
var result = _.map(projects, function(value, prop) {
  return { Name: prop, id: value };
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the array of objects. You can assign the key names by using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```js
var keys = ['Name','Id'];

var projects = {
 "project1": "11111",
 "project2": "22222",
 "project3": "33333",
};

var result = Object.keys(projects)
  .map(function(k) {
    return {
      [keys[0]]: k,
      [keys[1]]: projects[k]
    };
  });

console.log(result);
```